# eigenvalues of a Complex valued matrix in python with numpy.linalg

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, eigenvalue

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array(([1+2j,1-1j],[1-3j,2-1j]))
w , v = np.linalg.eig(a)
```

this code doesn't give me the right answer the eigenvalues are 2-j and 1+2j but this code gives me something else!
I need to find the exact answer...

Comment: Are you sure? Because `scipy.linalg.eigvals` gave the same output as `np.linalg.eig`.

Comment: I haven't tired what you said...
does it give the exact answer of the eigenvalues??

Comment: Check your math:  2-j and 1+2j are *not* eigenvalues of the given matrix.

Comment: @samansadrara, yes, it does! You may want to check your calculations!

Comment: @paul-shuvo thank you; does this code generally work for all matrixes with complex elements??

Comment: @samansadrara it should. But regardless, I think you should make sure that this gives you exactly what you want i.e. the `w`, `v` should match with your expected output. If it doesn't, then either your calculations are wrong or you are passing the wrong matrix (structure-wise).